# vscode using devcontainer.json with remote docker host

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

so I've been looking for a way to set vscode settings and specific versions of extensions on a project basis. And by projects I mean that 1 project would consist of a docker-compose file containing a bunch of services runing locally.

It seems you can enable/disable extensions in the workspace config file but not specify different versions across workspaces. I've been looking into dev containers as a potential solution. So this is a bit different from the recommended use case for dev containers, instead of running an instance of the vscode-server for each service in each container, I want to have a single container which has the code for all the services mounted to it purely for the purpose of installing extensions on a project basis. Also, I'm using vscodes ssh capabilities to develop on a remote server

It seems that using a remote docker host changes the way dev containers work, there's no  'Remote-Containers: Reopen in Container' option, and looking at the docs it seems that when you attach to a container as opposed to reopening in container it doesn't use the devcontainer.json file rather looks for an 'Attached container configuration' file, which I've tried adding but is not working either.

The docs get very sketchy at this intersection of remote containers and configuration files. So, I'm hoping someone can tell me if dev containers is a viable solution to this problem, and how I can get custom extensions and settings working with a remote docker host

thanks!